# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'msg.innerHTML="Upload ready...";)

Tags: javascript, image-uploading

I found a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CVYFN/) demonstrating as working file/image upload validation.

I have applied this script to my form, and I am receiving the following errors. 
**Note:** I have updated the script ([updated js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpardon/opar56kk/4/)) with the missing semicolon, however I am still receiving the following error:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'msg.innerHTML = "Upload ready..."')`

The error is directing attention to the following line:

```
mime.match(RegExp(accepted, 'i')) ? size > max ? (input.form.reset(), msg.innerHTML = max + "KB Exceeded!") : msg.innerHTML = "Upload ready..." : (input.form.reset(), msg.innerHTML = accepted + " file type(s) only!");
```

Comment: Probably means that `msg` is `undefined` and not what you think it is.

Comment: Oh also an `<input>` element can't have any "innerHTML" anyway - they're always empty.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/opar56kk/5/ use `no wrap - in <body>`, otherwise the script in jsfiddle is wrapped and your function `getImg` is out of scope.

Comment: @Cheery mistaken the `in<body` setting. Had it already in my body. Still getting this error.

Comment: @cpardon, where did you discover that missing semicolon? - there is no missing semicolon!

Answer (score 0):

One problem is the script wrapper in the fiddle.

But another problem is the `type`, sometimes when an unknown file type is used, `type` will be an empty string and `mimetype` will be undefined so value of mime becomes `undefined`.

One solution is to use the `mimetype` only of `type` is `undefined`

```
mime = (typeof test.type == 'undefined'? test.mimeType:test.type);
```

Another is to check whether `mime` has a value in the condition like

```js
// Image/File validation on Client-side
function getImg(input, max, accepted) {
  var upImg = new Image(),
    test, size, msg = input.form;
  msg = msg.elements[0].children[0];
  return input.files ? validate() : (upImg.src = input.value, upImg.onerror = upImg.onload = validate);

  function validate() {
    test = (input.files ? input.files[0] : upImg);
    size = (test.size || test.fileSize) / 1024;
    mime = (test.type || test.mimeType);

    mime && mime.match(RegExp(accepted, 'i')) ? size > max ? (input.form.reset(), msg.innerHTML = max + "KB Exceeded!") : msg.innerHTML = "Upload ready..." : (input.form.reset(), msg.innerHTML = accepted + " file type(s) only!");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Image upload</legend>
    <input type="file" onchange="getImg(this,11,'jpeg|jpg|png|gif')" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried both your solutions. Still getting the same error.

Comment: @cpardon the attached demo seems to be working for me... do you have an updated version where the issue is recreated... or were you able to recreate the issue using the above demo

Comment: Your update works in both `code snippet` & `js fiddle`. But when I add the script to my `body` below the `form` tag. Not sure?

Comment: @ArunPJohny, The mime-type of a "jpg" file extension, is: jpeg. Why did you add jpg?!